# How to upload an audio clip from react-native to php backend?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, reactjs, react-native

Tried many 3rd party librairies like axios,fetch,fetch-blob w/o success.
this code  includes my php backend.
using rn v 0.39

upload an audio clip that already exists in phone storage to server

file path : AudioUtils.MusicDirectoryPath + '/test.aac' [have access to the path , can play the clip ]

using reference: /github.com/g6ling/react-native-uploader

[Server response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heeJC.jpg)

"Could not retrieve file for uri /storage/emulated/0/Music/test.aac"

**Permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />                                                    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**React-native code**

```
const form= new FormData();

form.append('userfile', {
    uri:  AudioUtils.MusicDirectoryPath + '/test.aac',
    type: 'audio/aac', 
    name: 'userfile'
});

  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.open('post', `http://vidyarangam.com/next/upload_file`)
  xhr.send(form)
  xhr.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log('err', e)
 }
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if(this.readyState === this.DONE) {
  console.log(this.response)
 }
}
```

**php code**

```
function upload_file() {
    $droidinput = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $file = $droidinput['userfile']; // i have no idea how to upload it   
    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';    
    $config['allowed_types'] = '*';  
    $config['max_filename'] = '255';  
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;   
    $config['max_size'] = '1024'; //1 MB
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
        echo json_encode('status'=>'File upload error');       
    } else {
        echo json_encode('status'=>'File successfully uploaded');
    }          
}
```

Comment: And what exactly happens when your code is executed?

Comment: echo json_encode('status'=>'File upload error');

Comment: please check server response , how do i upload this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FIX**

used lib - react-native-fetch-blob

**code**

```
    import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';

    let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;

    let path_to_a_file = dirs.DownloadDir + '/header_logo.png';

  RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', 'http://192.168.43.236/upload.php', {
    Authorization : "Bearer access-token",
    otherHeader : "foo",
    'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data',
  }, [

    { name : 'header_logo', filename : 'header_logo.png', type:'image/foo', data:RNFetchBlob.wrap(path_to_a_file)},
  ]).then((resp) => {

    console.log(resp.text())

  }).catch((err) => {

    console.log(err)

  })
```

Comment: i am using above code and  getting response 201 from the server can you help me